Why doesn't net angular momentum vector coincide new axis of rotation in the case of gyroscopes?
Let's say we are given a gyroscope. Torque exerted by gravity will cause gyroscope to "flip" and hit the ground. Torque here coincides with the change of angular momentum vector. However, if it spins with high angular velocity around its axis (horizontal), gyroscope will start rotating around both horizontal (and hence we have constant angular momentum in x-axis) and vertical axis when left free. Angular momentum around axis + change of angular momentum will add up and give net angular momentum. Why is it so that this vector does not coincide with axes of rotation?
